# How to check whether a function exist in ruby and also with parameter

Tags: ruby, rspec, puppet

### My Ruby file

```
require 'puppet'

# ...

require 'googleauth'
module PuppetX
  module Puppetlabs
    module Google_cloud_dns
      class Provider < PuppetX::Puppetlabs::Swagger::Provider
        def client
          self.class.client
        end
```

### My RSpec file

I am using this two alternatively, but none of them working:

```
require_relative'../../lib/puppet_x/puppetlabs/google_cloud_dns/provider'
File.expand_path("../../lib/puppet_x/puppetlabs/google_cloud_dns/provider.rb",File.dirname(__FILE__)))

require 'spec_helper'
require_relative '../../lib/puppet_x/puppetlabs/google_cloud_dns/provider'
File.expand_path("../../lib/puppet_x/puppetlabs/google_cloud_dns/provider.rb", File.dirname(__FILE__))
describe Provider do
  it "checks function" do
    provide = Provider.new
    provide.should respond_to :client
  end
end
```

### The error which I am getting

```
rspec Mymodule/gc_dns/puppet-google_cloud_dns/spec/classes/provider_spec.rb --format documentation/home/vivekkumarmishra17/Mymodule/gc_dns/puppet-google_cloud_dns/spec/classes/provider_spec.rb:19:in `<top (required)>': uninitialized constant Provider (NameError)
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1361:in `load'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1361:in `block in load_spec_files'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1359:in `each'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/configuration.rb:1359:in `load_spec_files'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:106:in `setup'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:92:in `run'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:78:in `run'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/lib/rspec/core/runner.rb:45:in `invoke'
    from /var/lib/gems/1.9.1/gems/rspec-core-3.4.4/exe/rspec:4:in `<top (required)>'
    from /usr/local/bin/rspec:23:in `load'
    from /usr/local/bin/rspec:23:in `<main>'
```

Can anyone tell what I am doing wrong?

Comment: You could reference `Provider` with its actual name, which is nested inside a bunch of modules.

Comment: you could use the full name space or add `include PuppetX::Pupetlabs::Google_cloud_dns` to that file the reason it cannot find `Provider` is because it is namespaced as `PuppetX::Pupetlabs::Google_cloud_dns::Provider`

Comment: Thanks Dave and engineersmnky. It was very helpful.  However I am facing failure in my test cases like. 

describe PuppetX::Puppetlabs::Google_cloud_dns::Provider do 
it 'checks method client' do  subject = 
PuppetX::Puppetlabs::Google_cloud_dns::Provider.new  expect(subject).to receive(:client).with(:no_args) end
end


Failure/Error: expect(subject).to receive(:client).with(:no_args)      
Wrong number of arguments. Expected 0, got 1.

Comment: I am not sure why you want to test that client accepts no arguments but if you really want to `no_args` is a method not a symbol. [Docs] (http://www.rubydoc.info/gems/rspec-mocks/RSpec/Mocks/ArgumentMatchers). Right now you are using `:no_args` which counts as an argument.

Comment: Thanks engineersmnky